# C# double.TryParse with InvariantCulture returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double, culture

I'm trying to unit test a getprice method using NUnit. I am stuck with parsing the rawprice into double. My cultureinfo is `en-US` but I set it to `de-DE` for this test. Double parsing with numberstyles.any and invariantculture returns unexpected result.

The rawprice cultureinfo is unknown, it can be any. Also the server where it will run is also unknown and can be in any language.

For this test, I tried German for the rawprice and machine.

I tried parsing `"9,42"` but the result is `942`.

```
[Test]
[SetCulture("de-DE")]
public void GetPrice_PriceTextWithCommaDecimal_ReturnsInvariantPrice()
{
    var rawPriceText = "9,42";
    double.TryParse(rawPriceText, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double price);
    //parsed price result is 942

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what you expected. However, as far as what the code is doing, it's doing exactly what you told it to:

- Providing `NumberStyles.Any` tells `double.TryParse()` to allow *any* format, except `AllowHexSpecifier`. This includes the `AllowThousands` option.
- Providing the `InvariantCulture` causes parsing to use the `','` character as the thousands separator.
- Parsing doesn't actually care *where* a thousands separator appears. I.e. it doesn't actually force the separator to be in the location where it would indicate a thousands-multiple digit.

So, when you ask it to parse `"9,42"`, that text is interpreted using `InvariantCulture` (i.e. ignoring your current culture of `de-DE`), the `','` character is treated as a thousands separator (i.e. ignored for the purpose of computing the actual value), and you get the value `942`, just like you asked for.

If you don't want that result, you need to use different arguments for the call to `double.TryParse()`. You would need to explain what you *do* want if you want advice on what arguments you *should* use. All we can say given the information currently in your question is what arguments you apparently *don't* want.

Answer (score 8):

The cultures in `ToString` and `TryParse` must match.

It's either

```
        var s = rawPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //rawPrice becomes 9.42
        double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double price);
```

or

```
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        var s= rawPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        //rawPrice becomes 9,42
        double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out double price);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put your culture into the `TryParse` mechanism.

e.g.

```
double.TryParse(rawPriceText, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("de"), out double price);
```

For this case you could use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` instead of creating a new `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

You set the culture to `de-DE`.

But apparently you then decide to use the `InvariantCulture` instead, which will not recognize the `,` separator as decimal separator.

Using `CurrentCulture` instead will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I wanted to persist double values in a config file using invariant, whilst allowing users to enter data in local format.

This is the function I use.  A default value allows any badly formatted input to be reversed:

```
    private string DoubleValueFormatted(string text, double defaultValue)
    {
        var cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        var doubleValue = (double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, cultureInfo, out var value)) ? value : defaultValue;

        return doubleValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```